# Annotations affect how jackson writes types of every object and primitive

Tags: java, json, annotations, jackson, mapping

I think the annotations may interfere with the json output. The output prints objects with fields as integral, string, valueType and chars that it is not in the class. How to avoid this and get the simple json?

I'm using jackson-databind 2.8.9 with ObjectMapper.

**BaseEntity.java**

```
@MappedSuperclass
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5234608700757438450L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected Integer id;

    @Version
    @XmlTransient
    protected Integer version;
    ...
}
```

**Type.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="type")
@XmlRootElement
public class Type extends BaseEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    static final String PREFIX = "work.entity.WorkType.";
    public static final String findAll = PREFIX + "findAll";

    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 45)
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, length = 45)
    private String name;

    @Size(max = 45)
    @Column(name = "description", length = 45)
    private String description;
    ...
}
```

**Code**

```
...
Type type = new Type("Work);
type.setId(1);
type.setDescription("Duration months");
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.writeValueAsString(type)
...
```

**Json output the code before produces**

```
{
  "id" : {
    "integral" : true,
    "valueType" : "NUMBER"
  },
  "name" : {
    "string" : "Work",
    "valueType" : "STRING",
    "chars" : "Work"
  },
  "description" : {
    "string" : "Duration months",
    "valueType" : "STRING",
    "chars" : "Duration months"
  }
}
```

**Json that I want to obtain ¿?**

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  "name" : "Work",
  "description" : "Duration months",
}
```